# Why is this L2 a (closed) subspace of another L2?

Tags: measure-theory, hilbert-spaces, conditional-expectation

In a proof of the existence of a conditional expectation the following argument is used:

Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a sub-sigma-field of $\mathcal{G}$, wherein $(\Omega,\mathcal{G}, P)$ denotes a probability space.

Now it is claimed that $L^2(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ is a (closed) subspace of $L^2(\Omega,\mathcal{G},P)$. Here is my question:

Of course an element $f$ which is square-integrable and $\mathcal{F}$-measurable is square-integrable and $\mathcal{G}$-measurable. However, the $L^2$-spaces consist of equivalence classes. And the equivalence class of $f$ are not the same: Viewed as an element in $L^2(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ it consists of all $\mathcal{F}$-measurable-functions which are $a.s.$ equal to $f$.
Viewed as an element in $L^2(\Omega,\mathcal{G},P)$ it consists of all $\mathcal{G}$-measurable-functions which are $a.s.$ equal to it. Hence, how can this be a subspace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The author means that $ X = L^2(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P) $ is a subspace of $ Y = L^2(\Omega, \mathcal{G}, P) $ in the sense that there is a natural inclusion $ \iota : X \hookrightarrow Y $.   Let $ \tilde{X} $ denote the full set of square-integrable $ \mathcal{F} $-measurable functions so that $ X = \tilde{X} / \sim $ where $ \sim $ is the a.e. equivalence relation on $ \mathcal{F} $-measurable functions.  An important observation is that $ \sim $ is just the restriction of a.e. equivalence on $ \mathcal{G} $-measurable functions to $ \mathcal{F} $-measurable functions.

So if we define $ \tilde{\iota} : \tilde{X} \rightarrow \tilde{Y} $ by *actual* inclusion (every $ \mathcal{F}$-measurable function is indeed a $ \mathcal{G} $-measurable function) then $ \tilde{\iota} $ gives rise to a map $ \iota : X \rightarrow Y $.  Specifically, $ \iota $ is the unique map making the diagram commute
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
\tilde{X} @>{\tilde{\iota}}>> \tilde{Y} \\
@VVV @VVV\\
X @>{\iota}>> Y
\end{CD}
where the vertical arrows are the quotient maps.  Due to our observation about these quotient maps being "compatible", $ \iota $ is well-defined.  The inclusion $ \iota $ is what the author means when they say that $ X $ is a subspace of $ Y $.

Comment: Thank you very much for these explanations and sorry for my delayed response - i was very busy the last week.